# Element 'settings' cannot have character [children] because the type's content content-type is element-only

Tags: xml, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJIDEA 14.1.14 and created a Maven project using `maven-archetype-quickstart`.

### User Settings File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- localRepository-->
    | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
    |
    | Default: ~/.m2/repository
    <localRepository>/home/sandeep/Desktop/MyDocs/repos/maven-repos</localRepository>
    <pluginGroups>
    </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

Now, why does IntelliJIDEA pointing an error and how do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tampered somehow with the comment.

Remove the three lines starting with `|`.

The error is self descriptive: you can't have have characters nested within the `settings` XML element.